# what's "passing a filename argument"?

Tags: command-line, cat

I've been teaching myself the linux command line through a pdf book, and after the author explains how to use `cat` and `>` to make a text file, he says:

> We see that the result is the same as passing a
>   single filename argument.

and i really don't know what he means, despite the fact I haven't skipped over any part of the book. Is he just talking about putting in arguments in the terminal? If this is the case I still don't know what he means.

### EDIT

here's the whole paragraph:

> Using the “<” redirection operator, we change the source of standard
>   input from the keyboard to the file lazy_dog.txt. We see that the
>   result is the same as passing a single filename argument. This is not
>   particularly useful compared to passing a filename argument, but it
>   serves to demonstrate using a file as a source of standard input.

Comment: `<` and `>`? Can you quote a broader section, including the command the author showed before this quote?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my post, teaching me to put examples/dialogue in grey.....i didn't include much because he's just talking about how to use cat redirection, but here's the whole paragraph: Using the “<” redirection operator, we change the source of standard input from the
keyboard to the file lazy_dog.txt. We see that the result is the same as passing a
single filename argument. This is not particularly useful compared to passing a filename
argument, but it serves to demonstrate using a file as a source of standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *You shall pass (arguments)*

"*Passing an argument*" means adding a parameter after a specific command. The program launched by that command will behave consequently.

As an example, the command "***cp***" is used to copy a file and requires two arguments. Firstly the **SOURCE FILE** and secondly the **DESTINATION FILE (or destination directory)**. Please notice that syntax order is very important here.

```
cp <SOURCE FILE> <DESTINATION FILE>
```

Let's assume that you want to copy "*file.txt*" to "*copy_of_file.txt*". You have to run the command:

```
cp file.txt copy_of_file.txt
```

It will create a new file, in the same directory (the directory from which you ran the command, where the source file "*file.txt*" should be)

Both **SOURCE FILE** and **DESTINATION FILE** are arguments passed to the command "cp".

### Need some --help ?

If you want to know what or how many arguments a command needs, or what optionals arguments it accepts, you can do:

```
<command> --help
```

for example:

```
cp --help
```

or

```
cat --help
```

It will display the "How to use your command" into your terminal.

### Curiosity won't kill the *cat*

Let's take a look at the [cat command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucat.htm).
If you run *cat* with a single argument, let's say a text file :

```
cat my_file.txt
```

It will display the contents of that file on the terminal.

If you run cat with two arguments, it will display both file's contents:

```
cat my_first_file.txt my_second_file.txt
```

### The redirection operator ">"

Now, the > ([redirection operator](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php)) looks a bit more complex, but it's actually very simple.

It's a redirection. You have to look at everything that your terminal displays as an output from a command. The output usually goes to the terminal. If you run :

```
cat my_file.txt
```

The command is '*cat*', the argument is "my_file", and the output is the *content* of that file. The output goes to the terminal. Well, when you use  the redirection operator ">", which requires an argument, what you actually do is redirecting the output to another destination. So, what happens when you run

```
cat my_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

is that instead of displaying the content of the file into your terminal, it will be written into a file, "new_file.txt".

### There *is* two ways about it.

So basicaly, the result of

```
cat my_file.txt > copy.txt
```

and

```
cp my_file.txt > copy.txt
```

are the same : you create a new text file, with the content of another. But the process is very different.

One last thing :

```
> file.txt
```

while create an empty file (you redirect... nothing to file.txt, so it's empty. Pretty obvious isn't it ?)

Without more context, I'm not sure what the authors means, but I hope this helps. Good luck in learning unix, it's a bit hard to start with, but it ends with a lot of fun.

### **EDIT 1 :**

I almost forgot to answer :

"passing a filename argument" means passing an argument, and that argument must be a filename, so the name of a file, let's say "file.txt". It could also be the full path to the file, something like :

```
/home/user/Documents/file.txt
```

Comment: this is already fun for me, the thing i like about computers is that there's so much to understand, and linux doesn't bar you from understanding it like windows....not only that but ive found it to be a more stable OS

Comment: That's the spirit ! Enjoy.